# Is html or php header needed for gzip?

Tags: nginx, http, gzip, http-headers, html

I use gzip module of nginx to compress documents. When gzip is enabled nginx will automatically send content-ending of gzip with HTTP headers, right?

Without adding any PHP header `header()` or HTML meta `http-equiv`, this works perfectly. However, I have seen on online tutorial for adding header for gzip whether by PHP or HTML meta to assist browser to process gzipped data.

Is it really needed? Since I was not sure if this is needed on some conduction (that I am not testing), I asked this question for further clarification of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx compresses data on mime type. For static files it uses the mime.types file for this but for data from a backend you do need to set the mime type unless the default is already text/html or you've added the default to the types of be compressed. See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule#gzip_types

Comment: Yes, it compress text/html (by default), and without HTML or PHP header it successfully send gzip header. My question is whether I need to add gzip meta or header too? or nginx does this automatically?

Comment: Nginx will automatically add the gzip header.

Comment: Then adding PHP header is useless, right?

Comment: If nginx is compressing it then it will make sure the response is properly formatted. You don't need to do anything at all on PHP side.